# NODEJS - How to improve the performance by saving buffer in memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I'm trying to download some videos from an URL in node.js. I need the buffer of each one to send to a webservice.

Anyway, seems like my memory is being so consumed about it. Each video is about 100M and the ram used by the process goes from 90M to 500M, then after it, it goes back to 200M (seems like buffer is not being cleared by GC).

My code is the following:

```
request({ url: mediaURL, encoding: null }, (err, resp, bufferData) => {
    Logger.log(`Resolved buffer length: ${bufferData.length}`);
    buffer = bufferData;
    resolve();
});
```

My variable buffer is declared inside of the function (at the top). Also, when I don't need the buffer anymore, I do the following:

```
buffer = null;
```

But as I said, the memory goes back to 200MB (and not 90M like the initial)

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to improve the performance here?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show all your code?

Comment: To keep the memory footprint low, you can look at streams: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html and especially pipes: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options If you read through the documentation of the HTTP library that you are using (looks like "request" in your example), you can look for the terms stream / pipe.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippClaßen Actually the problem I've is that I need that buffer to send it to a function (that requires a buffer). So, it will always needs to be put on memory, right?